# Can I create a fake keyboard using an Atmega chip

Tags: atmega, atmel, keyboard

I have been wondering lately if I can make a "keyboard simulator". I have an Atmel Atmega chip and I know it can communicate by serial because they are used in Arduinos. Is it possible to write some code for the atmega then connect it to the pc using USB and make the PC think that the Atmega is a keyboard, I could then send it data/commands. Is this possible, if so how could I go about it?

Comment: This is one of the demos of the VUSB software implementation of USB, and should be an easy example project to find for the parts that have hardware USB as well (ie LUFA, Arduino Leonardo examples, etc).  Beyond a simple "Yes" this question isn't really a fit here as you are mostly looking for external resources.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you point me to a place or site I could ask this question then. Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: It can be accomplished using the atmega32u4: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/337

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a MCU. Look for one that is capable of more than USB-Serial, but can support the USB-HID Class (Human Interface Device Class) natively. Many manufacturers have example code for this.